# How to test function which returns a random React component in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test a function which returns a randomly selected React component from an array. Bellow, I have an array which is filled with different types of React components.

```js
collectionOfComponents = [
  <Component1 />
  <Component2 />
  <Component3 />
  <Component4 />
  <Component2 />
  <Component3 />
  ...
];
```

I then have a function which will select a random component from the array and return that component, as seen below.

```js
export default () => {
  const totalNumberOfComponents = collectionOfComponents.length;
  const randomComponentIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * totalNumberOfQuestions);
  const randomComponent = collectionOfComponents[randomComponentIndex];

  return cloneElement(randomComponent);
};
```

I am trying to write a unit test to cover this functionality, however, due the randomly returned React component is not as straight forward as I thought.

I have tried to mock the return of the function but this does not cover all the lines of the function in jests coverage report. Below is what I have tried.

```js
jest.mock('common/services/functionName', () => "Random Component");

it('should return random React component', () => {
  expect(functionName).toEqual('Random Component');
});
```

Comment: What are you testing ? Coverage for the sake of coverage is pointless. ----- Here you don't have control over the randomness, so you can't really test it. You may want to inject the random generator and therefore set it up before running the test. Like, if `rand()` generates `1` then return `Component 1` etc. ---- You could also run the function multiple times and assert that you got different result, but this would mean that you are more testing `Math.randoom()` rather than your code.

Comment: Well, Ideally I wanted to test to see if the function returned a React component, irrespective of what type. After reading Enzyme API documentation more I decided to use the below method. Your `What are you testing?` question made me think about what I really wanted to test which pointed me in the below direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking more about how to test the function without any mocking, I have decided to use the following approach by wrapping my function in a `div` container and checking if the wrapper contains any component from the `collectionOfComponents` array.

```js
it('should return random React component', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <div>
      {functionName()}
    </div>
  );

  expect(wrapper.containsAnyMatchingElements([
    ... collectionOfComponents,
  ])).toEqual(true);
});
```

I decided to use [containsAnyMatchingElements](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/containsAnyMatchingElements.html). Below is what the Enzyme API documentation says about it.

> Returns whether or not at least one of the given react elements in `patternNodes` matches an element in the wrapper's render tree. One or more elements of `patternNodes` must be matched one or more times. Matching follows the rules for containsMatchingElement.